# Converting Datetimes returns Null

Tags: datetime, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to convert a datetime that looks like this: 2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00 into EST, but i keep getting Null values when using the hive built in UTC conversion.

I've tried using a regular expression to parse the date:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") 
                - (cast(regexp_extract(regexp_extract(2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00, '(-[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])$', 1),'(-[0-9][0-9])',1) as int)*3600) -18000),'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

but that's not good, since there's an hourly difference based on the time of year.

I've also tried:

```
FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSS'ZZZZZ'") * 1000, 'EST')
```

and

```
FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:SSS'Z'") * 1000, 'EST')
```

but that appears to not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this method needs the date as a string like this:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

Normally, the date formats are for strings, not for integers or numbers.

Comment: I think it's more complex than that - how do you preserve time zone (this -07:00 at the end of the data string) ?

Comment: I can be (i'm not an expert sorry if I'm wrong), but in this link an other one I see that this method need string http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/

Comment: nah, that's correct - it's just how do you preserve the input's timezone. Like - you make it UTC (or local machine, would need to dig up which one it is) using your method, while my understanding is - it should be EST

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own by combining the two ways of running the query.

```
date_format(
 FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(
  (unix_timestamp('2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        + (cast(
              regexp_extract( 
                 regexp_extract('2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00', '(-[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])$',1),'(-[0-9][0-9])',1) as int)
         *-3600)
             )*1000 ,'America/New York')
            ,'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NULL` because the pattern (format of the date and time) you have provided is not matching with the actual date time value. Correcting the date time format in your query would resolve this issue:

```
select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2017-09-19T07:00:00-07:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Check out this link to know more about the date time patterns: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html